# how to detect if your code is running under pyspark

Tags: pyspark

For staging and production, my code will be running on PySpark. However, in my local development environment, I will not be running my code on PySpark.

This presents a problem from the standpoint of logging. Because one uses the Java library Log4J via Py4J when using PySpark, one will not be using Log4J for the local development.

Thankfully, the API for Log4J and the core Python logging module are the same: once you get a logger object, with either module you simply `debug()` or `info()` etc.

Thus, I wish to detect whether or not my code is being imported/run in PySpark or a non-PySpark environment: similar to:

```
class App:

    def our_logger(self):
        if self.running_under_spark():
            sc = SparkContext(conf=conf) 
            log4jLogger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j 
            log = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__) 
            log.warn("Hello World!")
            return log
        else:
            from loguru import logger
            return logger
```

**How might I implement `running_under_spark()`**

Simply trying to import `pyspark` and seeing if it works is not a fail-proof way of doing this because I have `pyspark` in my dev environment to kill warnings about non-imported modules in the code from my IDE.

Comment: Just to understand, 
[1] when you say develop code in "a non PySpark environment", will you be using pyspark objects? If yes, then are you not planning to test it?
[2] If no, and you will be using plain python, then why does the environment matter?
[3] Are you looking to recognise the environment and then decide what code to execute?

Comment: "a non PySpark environment" means no use of PySpark whatsoever to execute the same code (in development) that will also execute under PySpark (in production).

Comment: the reason environment matters has been explained in my update of the original post: because logging in Cython/non-PySpark cannot use Log4J but logging in PySpark must use Log4J.

Comment: You can check the spark session object created , is of which instance type, type of spark session object, for pyspark it would be `pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession ` and for non-pyspark it would be `org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession` for scala and java.  Hope this helps you to determine it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can set some environment variable in your spark environment that you check for at runtime ( in $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh):

```
export SPARKY=spark
```

Then you check if SPARKY exists to determine if you're in your spark environment.

```
from os import environ

class App:
def our_logger(self):
    if environ.get('SPARKY') is not None:
        sc = SparkContext(conf=conf) 
        log4jLogger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j 
        log = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__) 
        log.warn("Hello World!")
        return log
    else:
        from loguru import logger
        return logger
```